# Blender don't load udim

Tags: texturing, uv

I decided to use udim for my next project with substance painter, but blender wont load the textures no matter what i do, the 1001, 1002... naming in the textures are right, i tried to use diferent materials and i made a new model using the same uv, but nothing works.
I did the entire modeling and uv in blender 2.92

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "blender wont load the textures"? What are you trying to do exactly and how have you done it so far?

Comment: How have you named your images? In your screenshot, it's *"...eColor.png"*. The images should have a number at the end of the name, like *"body_diffuse.1001.png"*. You need to specify this name and Blender will find the related other tiles.

Comment: it is with the name, but the problem i found is that im using multiple shader in the same uv tile